# How to initialize variables referencing each other?

Tags: javascript

I'm using TypeScript with [validate-value](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validate-value) which uses [ajv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv) under the hood. I want to create validation schemas for filters similiar to [MongoDB operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/).

Each schema should have its own file but since it's possible to nest one filter into another I'm creating a circular reference before initializing the schemas. So I'm getting the error

> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'filterSchema' before initialization

How to reproduce the problem with plain Node and JS:

*package.json*

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node main.js"
  }
}
```

*main.js*

```
import { filterSchema } from "./filterSchemas/filterSchema.js";

console.log(filterSchema);
```

*.filterSchemas/filterSchema.js*

```
import { logicalOperatorSchema } from "./logicalOperatorSchema.js";

const filterSchema = {
  type: "object",
  oneOf: [logicalOperatorSchema],
};

export { filterSchema };
```

*.filterSchemas/logicalOperatorSchema.js*

```
import { notSchema } from "./notSchema.js";

const logicalOperatorSchema = {
  type: "object",
  oneOf: [notSchema],
};

export { logicalOperatorSchema };
```

*.filterSchemas/notSchema.js*

```
import { filterSchema } from "./filterSchema.js";

const notSchema = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    $not: filterSchema,
  },
  required: ["$not"],
  additionalProperties: false,
};

export { notSchema };
```

Do you have any suggestions how to solve this problem?

---

I also tried to put all schemas into a single file but that didn't solve the actual problem.

*schemas.js*

```
const notSchema = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    $not: filterSchema,
  },
  required: ["$not"],
  additionalProperties: false,
};
 
const logicalOperatorSchema = {
  type: "object",
  oneOf: [notSchema],
};
 
const filterSchema = {
  type: "object",
  oneOf: [logicalOperatorSchema],
};
 
export { filterSchema }
```

---

And I also do think that solving this problem solves the other one

```js
const foo = {
  x: bar
};

const bar = {
  y: foo
};

console.log(foo);
```

Comment: I'd say to merge them in a single file. Unfortunately there aren't that many solutions for circular references.

Comment: @nook this didn't work for me since I'm facing the same problem. I tried to put all schemas in a single file like so https://pastebin.com/gcx8U3in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, but it is not going to be useful.

```js
var foo = {
    x: bar
}

var bar = {
    y: foo
}

foo.x = bar
bar.y = foo

console.log(foo)
console.log(foo.x.y.x.y)
```

Comment: well I'm not sure if this is a good solution but that helped :)